# Where is thee callback happening in this code?

Tags: c++, callback, functor

```
    class Add
    {
      Add(){cout<<"ctor";}
      void operator()(int a ,int b){return a+b;}

    }
    int main()
    {
      Add(3,4);
    }
```

Add is the functor.And functor can help in callback mechanism right? So where is it happening here??

Comment: It isn't happening here.

Answer (score 2):

> And functor can help in callback mechanism right?

Yes. You could write a function template that uses a functor to perform a user-defined operation as part of whatever it's doing; for example:

```
template <typename Fn>
void do_stuff(Fn f, int a, int b) {
    int c = f(a, b);
    do_something(c);
}
```

and then inject your operation thusly:

```
do_stuff(Add(), 3, 4);
```

One specific use is the `std::sort` algorithm, which can use a user-supplied functor to compare types that don't support normal comparison operators.

> So where is it happening here??

It isn't; your code doesn't compile. After fixing the return value (since it returns a value not `void`), you could create and invoke a function with

```
Add()(3,4);
```

But that's not particularly useful.

Comment: In your above do_stuff method,u have passed Fn f as first parameter . Cant i just pass reference to a function instead. Can that be considered a substitute for functor? In other words, why use functors? Cant v just pass the reference to the function which needs to be called back??

Comment: @Nikhil: The advantage of functors (not this one, but in general) over functions is that they're objects, so they can bind data to code to form a *closure*. But it would take a whole chapter of a book to describe that properly.